# Industrial ownership

Tags: finance

One of the salient feature of single proprietorship is

> Enterprise and owner entity is same.

What does enterprise and owner entity refer to?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about business law and not about economics.

Comment: Hi Piyush, we normally don't handle questions like this one on this stack exchange, so this question will probably be closed. That being said, an "enterprise" is a business, and the "owner entity" is the individual (or legal entity) that owns it. In a sole proprietorship, the owner is also the manager of the business and is personally responsible for its debts; there's no corporate entity that separates the business from the person.